# How can I use Standard C libraries that are not supported in the Bionic C library to build with Android-NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, bionic, libm

My native source makes use of complex operations (defining ). These operations are implemented in the standard C99 math library but not in the bionic math library used by Android-NDK. 
For this reason I would like to make use of the Standard Math library in stead of the bionic math library to compile my source.

What are my possibilities?

Comment: Yank the relevant bits out of the math library and recompile?

Comment: Hi Seva, can you be a bit more specific? Do you mean that I should add the missing pieces to the bionic library and then recompile it?

Comment: I meant - to your own NDK library.